# apache 2.4 tomcat 8 Permission Denied

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-jk, tomcat8

I have an apache 2.4 on Debian Jessie and I host several sites as virtual hosts.
On of these sites is running on jsp so I hav installed tomcat 8 and I use mod_jk.

My virtual host configuration file for apache is:

```
<Directory /var/www/dimitros-apartments.gr>
                AllowOverride None
                Require all denied
        </Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName dimitros-apartments.gr
        ServerAlias www.dimitros-apartments.gr
        #<Location "/">
        #    JkUriSet worker ajp13:localhost:8009
        #</Location>
        JkMount /dimitros-apartments.gr/* ajp13_worker
        JkMount /dimitros-apartments.gr ajp13_worker

        DocumentRoot /var/www/dimitros-apartments.gr/web
#        DocumentRoot /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/dimitros-apartments.gr
#       ApJServMount /servlet /ROOT
#       <Directory "/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/dimitros-apartments.gr/WEB-INF">
#               Options None
#               Deny from all
#       </Directory>
        ServerAdmin admin@dimitros-apartments.gr
        ErrorLog /var/log/ispconfig/httpd/dimitros-apartments.gr/error.log
        Alias /error/ "/var/www/dimitros-apartments.gr/web/error/"
        ErrorDocument 400 /error/400.html
        ErrorDocument 401 /error/401.html
        ErrorDocument 403 /error/403.html
        ErrorDocument 404 /error/404.html
        ErrorDocument 405 /error/405.html
        ErrorDocument 500 /error/500.html
        ErrorDocument 502 /error/502.html
        ErrorDocument 503 /error/503.html

        <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
                </IfModule>

                <Directory /var/www/dimitros-apartments.gr/web>
                                # Clear PHP settings of this website
                                <FilesMatch ".+\.ph(p[345]?|t|tml)$">
                                                SetHandler None
                                </FilesMatch>
                                Options +FollowSymLinks +Indexes
                                AllowOverride None
                                Require all granted
               </Directory>
               <Directory /var/www/clients/client1/web12/web>
                                # Clear PHP settings of this website
                                <FilesMatch ".+\.ph(p[345]?|t|tml)$">
                                                SetHandler None
                                </FilesMatch>
 Options +FollowSymLinks +Indexes
                                AllowOverride None
                                Require all granted
                </Directory>




                # suexec enabled
                <IfModule mod_suexec.c>
                        SuexecUserGroup web12 client1
                </IfModule>
                # php as fast-cgi enabled
        # For config options see: http://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/mod/mod_fcgid.html
                <IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
                                FcgidIdleTimeout 300
                                FcgidProcessLifeTime 3600
                                # FcgidMaxProcesses 1000
                                FcgidMaxRequestsPerProcess 5000
                                FcgidMinProcessesPerClass 0
                                FcgidMaxProcessesPerClass 10
                                FcgidConnectTimeout 3
                                FcgidIOTimeout 600
                                FcgidBusyTimeout 3600
                                FcgidMaxRequestLen 1073741824
                </IfModule>
                #<Directory /var/www/dimitros-apartments.gr/web>
                #               <FilesMatch "\.php[345]?$">
                #                       SetHandler fcgid-script
                #               </FilesMatch>
                #               FCGIWrapper /var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/web12/.php-fcgi-starter .php
                #               FCGIWrapper /var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/web12/.php-fcgi-starter .php3
                #               FCGIWrapper /var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/web12/.php-fcgi-starter .php4
                #               FCGIWrapper /var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/web12/.php-fcgi-starter .php5
                #               Options +ExecCGI
                #               AllowOverride All
                #                                               Require all granted
                #                               </Directory>
                #<Directory /var/www/clients/client1/web12/web>
                #               <FilesMatch "\.php[345]?$">
                #                       SetHandler fcgid-script
                #               </FilesMatch>
                #               FCGIWrapper /var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/web12/.php-fcgi-starter .php
                #               FCGIWrapper /var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/web12/.php-fcgi-starter .php3
                #               FCGIWrapper /var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/web12/.php-fcgi-starter .php4
                #               FCGIWrapper /var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/web12/.php-fcgi-starter .php5
                #               Options +ExecCGI
                #               AllowOverride All
                #               Require all granted
                #       </Directory>
                # add support for apache mpm_itk
                <IfModule mpm_itk_module>
                        AssignUserId web12 client1
                </IfModule>

                <IfModule mod_dav_fs.c>
                # Do not execute PHP files in webdav directory
                        <Directory /var/www/clients/client1/web12/webdav>
                                <ifModule mod_security2.c>
                                        SecRuleRemoveById 960015
                                        SecRuleRemoveById 960032
                                </ifModule>
                                <FilesMatch "\.ph(p3?|tml)$">
                                        SetHandler None
                                </FilesMatch>
                        </Directory>
                        DavLockDB /var/www/clients/client1/web12/tmp/DavLock
                        # DO NOT REMOVE THE COMMENTS!
                        # IF YOU REMOVE THEM, WEBDAV WILL NOT WORK ANYMORE!
      # WEBDAV BEGIN
                        # WEBDAV END
                </IfModule>



</VirtualHost>
```

On tomcat's server.xml I have a host record as:

```
<Host name="www.dimitros-apartments.gr" appBase="/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps" >
    <Alias>dimitros-apartments.gr</Alias>
    <Context path="" docBase="/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/dimitros-apartments.gr" />
```

Site is running here http://www.dimitros-apartments.gr

I get a permission denied error where I access http://www.dimitros-apartments.gr.

I use ispconfig and for each domain I must have it's directory where apache's domains directories resides, regardless if this domain is served from apache or in my case from tomcat. So for this domain I have a corresponding directory on both apache and tomcat. I also have an index.jsp on both tomcat domain root directory and apache's domain root directory.

When I access http://www.dimitros-apartments.gr/index.jsp I get an uncompiled jsp page ( I see the source code ) on my browser.
A strange think is that this uncompiled page, is not from tomcat's directory but from apache's domain directory.

any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Christoforos

Answer (score 0):

It seems I was looking on old documentation. For everyone might have the same problem, the lines

```
JkMount /dimitros-apartments.gr/* ajp13_worker
 JkMount /dimitros-apartments.gr ajp13_worker
```

must change to

```
JkMount /* ajp13_worker
```